# Selenium.webdriver: Chrome failed to start: crashed. when running as Cronjob

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cron, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get my selenium script running as Cron.
The script is running without problems on the terminal and gives me the desired output.
But running as Cron I get the Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

This is my driver initialisation. I added everything that should fixed the issue into the Code but it didn't worked for me:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
chrome_options.headless = True
caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["marionette"] = True
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver',options=chrome_options) # <-here it crashes
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
```

chromedriver --version and whereis chromedriver:

```
ChromeDriver 86.0.4240.22 (398b0743353ff36fb1b82468f63a3a93b4e2e89e-refs/branch-heads/4240@{#378})
chromedriver: /usr/bin/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

google-chrome --version and whereis google-chrome:

```
Google Chrome 86.0.4240.183
google-chrome: /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Like i said before it's working manuel on the terminal but with this cronjob i get the error above:

```
*/5 * * * * user ~/HTGMQ/run.sh
```

run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/HTGMQ/ # i know its redundant but who cares
/usr/bin/python3 ~/HTGMQ/script.py
```

I really don't know what I should do anymore :(

Thx for replies and answers

Comment: try without "--profile-directory=Default".  (That won't work if someone is currently using that profile...)

Comment: unfortunately I'm getting still the same error

Comment: Try to add `DISPLAY:=0` at the top of your Cron job. I ran into the same issue and that fixed it for me.